# Sendgrid Always Sends Text Email

Tags: html, node.js, email, sendgrid

I have an HTML sendgrid template and am sending it via Node.js using the npm package 'sendgrid'. Problem is that I always receive the email as text format not HTML even though the template has HTML.

Code:

```
var email = new sendgrid.Email({
    to      : 'me@here.com',
    from    : 'you@there.com',
    subject : 'Saying Hi with HTML Template',
    text    : 'Body'    //This is required
});

email.addFilter('templates', 'enable', 1);
email.addFilter('templates', 'template_id', '12131331.....');
email.addSubstitution('{{TOKEN1}}', 'value');

sendgrid.send(email, function(err, json) {
    if (err) { console.error(err); }
    console.log(json);
});
```

Template

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
  <h1>This is a test</h1>
  <p>{{TOKEN1}}</p>
  <p><a href="http://www.there.com">There</a></p>

  <div>&lt;%body%&gt;</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a code parameter I'm supposed to set? Or a setting on the template itself to allow HTML?

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/nodejs.html). You need to set the HTML of the Email object, not the Text.

Comment: I see thanks. <%body %> is required even if it's not needed.

Comment: I believe 'text' is a fallback in the event the email client does not support HTML emails.

Comment: Yep. I was thinking I could put all my html in the template and just use substitutions, but I see that I must put at least a "." in the html field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs#usage). You only use the text property if you're sending plain-text. Instead, use the html property to create an HTML message. You can use the built in `setHtml` method like the following:

```
var email     = new sendgrid.Email(); 
email.setHtml('<h1>Some html</h1>');
sendgrid.send(email, function(err, json) { });
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are not using SendGrid API but System.Net.Mail classes with sendgrid below setting will do it:

```
EmailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Comment: And what about the text only option, many spam checkers will try to find if there is one, and can potentially mark as spam if no plain/text version is found.